# Gradient layer is not working on landscape mode. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I have added a gradient layer in my view its working perfect in portrait mode bit in its not working in landscape mode.

[image]

[image]

```
 func createGredientBackground() {

    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    let center = UIColor(red: 249 / 255, green: 150 / 255, blue: 107 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let end = UIColor(red: 247 / 255, green: 93 / 255, blue: 89 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let start = UIColor(red: 255 / 255, green: 229 / 255, blue: 180 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor

    layer.colors = [start, center,end]
    layer.frame = self.view.bounds //self.view.frame
    print(layer.frame)
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)

}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sublayers are not automatically resized to fit the view: you should update them when the view gets its layout pass:

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
}
```

Didn't try it, so maybe you should also try with `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Comment: I have the same problem. But the gradient after updating them is absolutely different. Why is that?